# Remove commented lines except one comment using sed

Tags: sed

Not very familiar with complex usages of `sed`, but I have this requirement now. I have a file 1.txt with contents in the following pattern:

```
sree@amby01:/home/sree : cat 1.txt
SSL
 this first line
#comment line
 second line
# third comment
# line nline
#ApiText
lkjfl
# my line
your line
sree@amby01:/home/sree :
```

Now, I want to remove the commented lines between the block `SSL....#ApiText`, but the line `#ApiText` should not be removed.

The output should look like this:

```
SSL
this first line
 second line
#ApiText
```

Its a bash shell. I know how to remove commented lines alone, but not how to remove commented lines except when the comment is following by a certain text. I can use only `sed`.

Comment: "I can only use `sed`"... Um... why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways but one from several can be:

```
sed '/SSL/,/#ApiText/{//b;/^#/d}' 1.txt
```

- `/SSL/,/#ApiText/` - address range where commands will be executed
- `//` - for line(s) with previous regexp (`SSL` or `#ApiText` - any of found)
- `b` - go to end of instructions ( mean *to do nothing*)
- `/^#/d` - delete(do not print) lines which starts by `#`

Comment: could you also explain briefly how this works?

Comment: @spasic Code is very simple but if you like

Comment: @Costas thanks, when you put it like that, it feels very simple.. but before your explanation it was all greek to me